# Finding the radius, diameter, area and circumference of a circle

Tags: java

So I'm still new to programming and I don't know if this is all correct or not, but I'm trying to find the area circumference of a circle with a given radius.

So far I have this:

```
public class Circle  {

   private double radius;

   public Circle(double r) {

   }

   public double getRadius()  {
      return radius;
   }

   public void setRadius(double r)  {
   }

   public double diameter()  {
      double diameter = radius * radius;
      return diameter;
   }

   public double area()   {
      double area = Math.PI * (radius * radius);
      return area;
   }

   public double circumference()   {
      double circumference = 2 * Math.PI * radius;
      return circumference;
   }
}
```

I also have this other part too...

```
public class CircleTest {
   private static void circleTest (int r) {
      Circle circleTest = new Circle(-2);
      System.out.printf("Parameter: %d%n", r);
      System.out.printf("Radius: %.1f %n", circleTest.getRadius());
      System.out.printf("Diameter: %.1f %n", circleTest.diameter());
      System.out.printf("Area: %.1f %n", circleTest.area());
      System.out.printf("Circumference: %.1f %n", circleTest.circumference());
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {

   }
}
```

I don't know if this is right or not, but it compiles just fine but it doesn't print anything out when I run it. What am I doing wrong???

Comment: Why are you passing a negative radius and why is your constructor blank inside? How do you think radius gets a value in your program?

Comment: Your `main` method is empty, which means it will do nothing.

Comment: You have diameter as r^2 ...  Programming doesn't matter if you don't know math.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code has few mistakes . it has to be like this

```
public class Circle  {

   private double radius;

   public Circle(double r) {
    radius = r;

   }

   public double getRadius()  {
      return radius;
   }

   public void setRadius(double r)  {
   }

   public double diameter()  {
      double diameter = radius * radius;
      return diameter;
   }

   public double area()   {
      double area = Math.PI * (radius * radius);
      return area;
   }

   public double circumference()   {
      double circumference = 2 * Math.PI * radius;
      return circumference;
   }
}
```

main class has to be like this

```
public class CircleTest {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
         Circle circleTest = new Circle(-2);
              System.out.printf("Parameter: %d%n", r);
              System.out.printf("Radius: %.1f %n", circleTest.getRadius());
               System.out.printf("Diameter: %.1f %n", circleTest.diameter());
              System.out.printf("Area: %.1f %n", circleTest.area());
              System.out.printf("Circumference: %.1f %n", circleTest.circumference());
           }
        }
```

mistakes you have made 1) your code has to be in main method .2) the constructor parameter has to be set to the class variable.

Answer (score -1):

In the Java language, when you execute a class with the Java interpreter, the runtime system starts by calling the class's main() method.

[The Java Main Method](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr96/cs333/java/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/main.html)

You should put some code in this block

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

   }
```